# File input with a string as ajax parameter separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make an ajax call which has 2 parameters value. One file object and another string value. I need to pass 2 parameters as service will accept 2 parameters. I have written like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: serviceParameter.url,
                dataType: "JSON",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {fileInput: fileobject, uploadType: 'test'},
                //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                //processData: false, // Don't process the files
                //contentType: false,
                contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(e){console.log(e);}
            })
```

It giving 404 not found exception. Please help me with some idea.

Comment: check you backend response.

Comment: And in your network tab?